# Tuple error (numpy)

Tags: python, numpy

I padded my data using `np.pad(x,[(0,0)], mode='constant')` and got this error:

```
ValueError: Unable to create correctly shaped tuple from [(0, 0).
```

My `x` has  shape (21, 4) and I want to pad it to get a shape of (22,4).

Does anyone know what is happening?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What is `x` here? What is the input and expected output here?

Answer (score 2):

The rank of the first argument has to match the number of pairs in the second argument.

For example, observe that this gives the error that you see:

```
>>> x = np.ones((21, 4))
>>> np.pad(x, [(0,0)], mode='constant')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...snip...]
ValueError: Unable to create correctly shaped tuple from [(0, 0)]
```

The problem is that `x` has rank 2 but the second argument has only one pair, not two.

However, if we supply a second argument with two pairs, this succeeds:

```
>>> x2 = np.pad(x, [(0,0), (0,0)], mode='constant')
```

To get the final dimension that you want, we have to pad the first dimension by 1.  One way to do that is:

```
>>> x2 = np.pad(x, [(0,1), (0,0)], mode='constant')
>>> x2.shape
(22, 4)
```

Comment: isn't the argument to `pad` supposed to be in general list of tuples (one per axis)?

Comment: Thank you so much @John1024